# how to run sgi-irix programs x64 windows?

Tags: windows, irix

I recently need to run a program Metro:
http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/downloads/downloads.htm

It is used to measure the difference between two 3d models.

However, this program has to be run in irix 6.2/6.3. But I only have a win8.1 laptop. Is there any way to run it in a shell like cygwin? Or is there any available virtual machine resource of irix platform?

Thanks!

Comment: If you read the page describing the Metro software a bit more closely you'll find that they have released a version for Windows. I'd try that.

Comment: I know it: <http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/downloads/downloads.htm> provides windows version of metro 3.1. However, what is strange is that, the program in sourceforge is called 'trimeshinfo'. I've tried it, it does not provide the function described in Metro. It can only read a file and extract some mesh info.

Comment: Porting software that uses graphics or other platform specifics from IRIX to Windows is most likely going to be pretty hard, and as far as I know there are no emulators capable of running IRIX either (not that the OS is available without a license), so your best bet is either to get yourself a SGI box or find some other software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software you're trying to run is old enough to drive in most countries (compiled in 1998), and was compiled for an operating system that doesn't exist anymore (Irix) that ran on a CPU architecture that's no longer even used for desktop computers (MIPS-II) and was released by a company that doesn't exist anymore either (SGI).

Your chances of getting it to run are practically nil without some *major* retrocomputing work. Sorry.

Comment: very comprehensive! Thank you ~~

Comment: A small correction: There are still some machines around that are actually used. I know because I am using one right now every day. And there is even support available from HP, which bought Compaq, which had bought SGI. but it *is* painfulto develop SW for it becaus emodern toolchains don't support it anymore...